# Using type -t command in linux c.?

Tags: c, shell, popen

I use `popen` to execute `type -t type` , this give me an error message `-t` not found. When I perform `type -t type` in the shell this gives me **builtin**. Why doesn't this work with `popen`?

Comment: Maybe show the code you have written? And is that a compiler error message or a runtime error?

Comment: FILE* file = popen("type -t type", "w"); This error appears at runtime in the standard output. When I use type -t type directly in the shell i get builtin. (no error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX specifies that the shell used with `popen` is `/bin/sh`. Your interactive shell is probably `bash`. The behaviour of the `type` command is different for `sh` and `bash`. `sh` does not support `-t`.

Your system probably has `/bin/sh` symbolically linked to `/bin/dash`, but that's just an implementation detail.

If you need `bash` behaviour, run `bash` explicitly:

```
   popen("/bin/bash -c 'type -t type'", "r")
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/9zEZzU).

Comment: My interactive shell is bash. Ok -t is not supported in sh that explains. Thank you for your answer. Is there a workaround? Is there another command that gives me the result builtin when its a builtin command and file if it is a program?

Comment: Fantastic this works. :-) How can I use the output (builtin, file) of popen("/bin/bash -c 'type -t type'", "r") in an if statement?

Comment: I see that it put ultin and ile instead of builtin and file on the output. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Where? Show your code. If you need it to print to the output, change `"r"` to `"w"` obviously.

Comment: I see uiltin and ile (instead of builtin and file) in the shell. I want to use the result builtin or file in an if statement in a c program.

Comment: Please ask a different question. Show *all* the code.